# Trigger insert -doesn't fire on real table with where clause

Tags: t-sql, triggers, insert

Hi I created trigger insert which work fine on test field 
1. when i copy data to table on which trigger is set or i use code insert into.
The insert look like this:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON GO
Create TRIGGER sometr ON [dbo].[mpomiar] For INSERT
 AS
Begin 
iNSERT INTO  
[Database].dbo.[eksport] ([Repair_Date],[idKard],[Position],[error][Pos_X],[Pos_Y],[Pos_Z],[name],[model],[parent]) 

SELECT i.[Repair_Date],c.idKard,i.[Position],i.error,i.[Pos_X],i.[Pos_Y],i.[Pos_Theta],s.name, mo.Model, pn.Parent 

FROM inserted i
 inner join dbo.test t on i.idtst=t.idtst

 inner join dbo.Kard c on t.idKard=c.idKard

 inner join dbo.TFILE AS s ON t.idTFILE = s.idTFILE INNER JOIN

        dbo.MACHINE AS mc ON t.idMC = mc.idMC INNER JOIN

         dbo.PANEL AS p ON c.idPANEL = p.idPANEL INNER JOIN

        dbo.PARENT AS pn ON i.idPARENT = pn.idPARENT INNER JOIN

         dbo.MODEL AS mo ON pn.idMOD = mo.idMOD

where [Repair_Error] in (400,300)     and c.idKard not in (select idKard from dbo.eksport)

end
```

But when the trigger is set on real table in the MS SQL Server 2005 it only fire when i delete from code

> > where [Repair_Error] in (400,300)     and c.idKard not in (select idKard from dbo.eksport)

Answer (score 0):

We tested trigger and it works without:

```
where [Repair_Error] in (400,300)
```

but it works with:

```
where c.idKard not in (select idKard from dbo.eksport)
```

The trigger must work `with where [Repair_Error] in (400,300)`